# Get user where user year greater than Time.now - 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activemodel

I want to get all users whose age is greater than 4 in query. I have tried this but i am not able to get year of user date_of_birthday attribute. How can we get year or is there any easy way to do so.

```
User.where('date_of_birth.year < ?',Time.now - 4)
```

Comment: `Time.now - 4.years => 2012-05-27 09:44:27 -0400`

Comment: Issue is with date_of_birth.year , not letting me get year of date_of_birth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your `date_of_birth` is a date data type, you can still search based on a `DateTime` or simply just `Time`.

So you can search your User modem with where the birthday is makes the user at least 4 years old. This would take into account not only their year of birth but the month and day as well.

```
2.3.1 :001 > User.where('birthday < ?', DateTime.now - 4.years).size
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE (birthday < '2012-05-27 13:51:49.162909')
 => 51
```

You can see here that the birthday attribute in my example is a Date data type, not a time.

```
2.3.1 :003 > User.where('birthday < ?', DateTime.now - 4.years).first.birthday
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (birthday < '2012-05-27 13:52:09.802729') ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 => Mon, 02 May 1960
```